# `clear_transaction_record_state': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when creating a record Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration

I'm creating a standalone project in ruby. I wanted to have the same migration as rails so i have installed the gem [standalone-migrations](https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations). I created my database using this config.yml `development:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: gametour
      encoding: utf8
      host: localhost
      username: tylo
      password: ~`

then there how i created my first migration :

```
rake db:new_migration name=flower_type_migration

class FlowerTypeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :flowerTypes do |t|
       t.string    :type
    end
 end
end

rake db:migrate
```

It seems like rake db:migrate works fine since i can see the database and table in psql.

but when i try to create a record in ruby :

```
FlowerTypes.create(:type => "test"}
```

i get this error :

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:425:in 'clear_transaction_record_state': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:339:in 'ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:339:in 'rollback_active_record_state!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in 'save'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in 'save'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in 'create'
```

i have tried to grant privileges to myself (tylo) and to PUBLIC but still get the same error.

I must be missing something, is there any solution to this ?

Comment: What happens if you `SELECT * FROM "flowerTypes";`? Unquoted identifiers are folded to lower case in PostgreSQL so if you create a mixed case table name then you have to quote it everywhere.

Comment: It worked with the quote yes haha. I thought this problem was related to the ruby one but it seems like its not the case, have you any idea about the create not working ? Thank you btw i didn't know that.

Comment: (1) Best practise with PostgreSQL is to create table names (and other identifiers) in lower case with underscores to separate words, that way you never have to worry about quoting. (2) I don't see a `name` column in that table but you're trying to create a record with a `name`.

Comment: Yes it make sense. Sorry i wrote those by hand,  i did a mistake there but i wrote :type in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure out why i'm getting this error. It was because of the "initialize" in my ruby class, i imagine it overwrite the "normal" one.